# Leveraging Powershell to Backup MySites

Tags: site-collection, my-site, backup

Looking to backup the MySites that i have in my 2010 farm on a regular basis so that we can hold on to them incase they contain content in them that might be needed after a user leaves...

Any way to do this in PowerShell? I have a simple script that will do one site collection in a web application but am not sure how to do multiples as the mysites are essentially their own site collections within the web application.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this with out leveraging a 3rd party tool and relying on PowerShell to do the work?

Comment: Are your MySites under their own web application?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to be able to individually restore a mysite user site collection if needed to access the content in it....

Comment: Then you should be able to use powershell to get a hook on your web application holding your My Sites and for each over all the site collections and back them up